# html_quickform 1, change checkbox default value?

Tags: checkbox, default, pear, quickform

I'm trying to change a checkbox default value (which is 1) to something else with HTML_Quickform.

```
$form->addElement('checkbox', 'people', 'Personnel et étudiants :', array('value' => 'Personnel et étudiants'));
```

But it doesn't work. The value is still 1.
I'm using Quickform 1.164 and I can't use a new version (it's integrated to a massive framework and there is a lot of work if I want to update/check all existing forms).

Any idea?